# HTTP Requests made with file_get_contents() share the same session data?

Tags: php, session, file-get-contents

I've got a problem...

I've a MVC-like framework and the redirect mechanism allows me too get snippets of HTML code generated by PHP on a remote host.

I'm getting these snippets by using the file_get_contents() function, with allow_url_fopen turned on.

The problem is the fact I use session data inside these code fragments and the session data is  being lost every time. I'm assuming this new request is not sharing the same session data and therefore I need a way to get these fragments without losing my session data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wait... you're using a remote file_get_contents call as an include? As in you're fetching PHP source code from a website and then executing it?

Comment: Interesting, but we need to know more details, whether the code is from a **remote machine**, the session will get lost, as its obviously cookie based and your not using cookies in the fgc. You might be better off using curl with `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` its also very trivial to eval the code. `ob_start(); eval('?>'.$code); $evaled=ob_get_clean();`. If its not remote then use `included()`

Comment: Use include, not file_get_contents.

Comment: No, not using it as an include. I'm fetching HTML code generated by PHP scripts and then displaying it. A little bit different.

Comment: Then you need to use the cookie options on cURL, use cURL instead of file_get_contents, and preserve the cookie between PHP scripts if necessary.

Comment: So the files you get are on a seperate server / domain? In that case the sessions will not match anyhow. Why do you need to do this

Comment: Same server/domain. I just needed to have the PHP code inside these fragments processed and when I requested them using file_get_contents with an path ( like file_get_contents('snippets/test.php'), i.e., using the file:/// protocol, this wasn't happening, so I decided to use file_get_contents with the http:// protocol and started using file_get_contents( 'http://mywebsite.com/snippets/test.php' ) instead. It solved the PHP processing problem, but created this new session problem.

But I used include, as suggested by @user574632 above and it worked fine.

Thanks you all!

Comment: No problem, i added that as an answer for future visitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files your accessing are on the same server as the calling file then you might as well use `include();` like @user574632's answer.

But if not, to keep the session you will need to handle the cookies the server sends;

Sessions are cookie based, server sets the session cookie your browser picks it up and uses it for all subsequent requests.

By default `file_get_contents` wont handle cookies, so your need to grab the header from the server by accessing `$http_response_header` array and then match with regex the `Set-Cookie:` header then store that and on following requests use the cookie and create a stream context with the cookie added to the header and pass that to fgc:

```
<?php 
function get_cookies() {
    //check cookies folder - or make it
    if(!file_exists('./cookies/')){
        mkdir('./cookies/', 0755, true);
    }
    $return = null;
    foreach(glob("./cookies/*.txt") as $file) {
        $return .= file_get_contents($file).';';
    }
    return $return;
}

function save_cookies($http_response_header) {
    print_r($http_response_header);
    foreach($http_response_header as $header) {
        if(substr($header, 0, 10) == 'Set-Cookie'){
            if(preg_match('@Set-Cookie: (([^=]+)=[^;]+)@i', $header, $matches)) {
                $fp = fopen('./cookies/'.$matches[2].'.txt', 'w');
                fwrite($fp, $matches[1]);
                fclose($fp);
            }
        }
    }
}

$opts = array('http' =>
    array('header'=>'Cookie: '.get_cookies()."\r\n")
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$contents = file_get_contents('http://mywebsite.com/snippets/', false, $context);
save_cookies($http_response_header);

echo $contents;
?>
```

Alternatively you should use curl instead its faster and handles cookies fine.

So something like the following, use curl and then revert to fgc if curl is not present, all wrapped up with cookie support in a class, so the 3 functions are contained:

```
<?php
//example usage
echo new curl_get_contents('http://example.com/page_that_needs_sessions');

class curl_get_contents{
    public $result;

    function __construct($url){
        $this->curl_rev_fgc($url);
    }

    function __toString(){
        return $this->result;
    }

    private function get_cookies() {
        $return = null;

        foreach(glob("./cookies/*.txt") as $file) {
            $return .= file_get_contents($file).';';
        }
        return $return;
    }

    private function save_cookies($http_response_header) {
        foreach($http_response_header as $header) {
            if(substr($header, 0, 10) == 'Set-Cookie'){
                if(preg_match('@Set-Cookie: (([^=]+)=[^;]+)@i', $header, $matches)) {
                    $fp = fopen('./'.$matches[2].'.txt', 'w');
                    fwrite($fp, $matches[1]);
                    fclose($fp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private function curl_rev_fgc($url){
        //check cookies folder - or make it
        if(!file_exists('./cookies')){
            mkdir('./cookies/', 0755, true);
        }

        $usragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yourbot/0.1; +https://yoursite/bot.html)';

        //Check curl is installed or revert to file_get_contents()
        $curl = function_exists('curl_init') ? true : false;

        if($curl){
            $opts = array(
            'http' => array(
            'method' => "GET",
            'header' => 'Cookie: '.$this->get_cookies().'\r\n', // cookie in fgc support
            'user_agent' => $usragent)
            );
            $context = stream_context_create($opts);
            $result  = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
            $this->save_cookies($http_response_header);

            if(empty($result)){
                $this->result = 'Error fetching: '.htmlentities($url);
            }else{
                $this->result = $result;
            }
            return;
        }

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $usragent);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        if(!file_exists('./cookies/curl.txt')){
            file_put_contents('./cookies/curl.txt',null);
        }
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, './cookies/curl.txt');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  './cookies/curl.txt');

        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        if(empty($result)){
            $this->result = 'Error fetching: '.htmlentities($url);
        }else{
            $this->result = $result;
        }
        curl_close($curl);

        return;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for accept, im fixing the fgc cookies bit now.

Answer (score 0):

Use include instead. If you need to read the output into a variable to display later/elsewhere in the code, as suggested in the comments, use the output buffer:

```
ob_start();
include('path/to/file.php');

$included = ob_get_clean();

//nothing has been output to the browser yet

//later on

echo $included;
```

Comment: Note the *remote host* in question so, this would only work if you have `allow_url_include = On` which should never be on.

Comment: @LozCheroneツ The files are NOT on a remote server, according to the latest comments.

Comment: The files are in the same server. It was my mistake when i said "remote host" in the question. Sorry.